# wget: unable to resolve host address `http'

Tags: http, ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-12.04, wget

I am getting this strange thing on my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit machine when I do a `wget`

```
$ wget google.com

--2014-07-18 14:44:32--  http://google.com/

Resolving http (http)... failed: Name or service not known.

wget: unable to resolve host address `http'
```

I have encountered this problem earlier when I got it for any web pages (and not http), which required me to add my nameserver to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

However, here that doesn't seem to be the problem, instead it is recognizing `http` as something different. Any advise?

Comment: can you ping google.com?

Comment: you won't be able to wget anything then. You have an issue with your nameserver configuration. As @WhiteCoffee suggests below, add in the google public DNS servers and try to ping then. If that works, wget should work.

Comment: You cannot use ping for some proxies.  Nor can you use a DNS lookup from the client in question.  Some corporate networks do not allow external resolution.  The proxy server must handle that.  I suspect in @techEnthusiast's case, the proxy is required to handle the DNS.

Answer (score 81):

The DNS server seems out of order. You can use another DNS server such as 8.8.8.8. Put `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the **first line** of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: why exactly 8.8.8.8

Comment: @Mouin 8.8.8.8 is the [Google public DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) which is a common used server, if you are looking for a open/democratic one have a look at: https://www.opennicproject.org/

Answer (score 15):

remove the `http` or `https` from `wget https:github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/archive/master.zip` . this worked fine for me.

Comment: It works for me too. but why I used prefix http or https succeed before?

Comment: Why tf does this work?

Answer (score 10):

I have this issue too. I suspect there is an issue with DigitalOcean’s nameservers, so this will likely affect a lot of other people too.
Here’s what I’ve done to temporarily get around it - but someone else might be able to advise on a better long-term fix:

1. Make sure your DNS Resolver config file is writable:

   `sudo chmod o+r /etc/resolv.conf`
2. Temporarily change your DNS to use Google’s nameservers instead of DigitalOcean’s:

   `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

Change the IP address in the file to: `8.8.8.8`

Press `CTRL` `+` `X` to save the file.

This is only a temporary fix as this file is automatically written/updated by the server, however, I’ve not yet worked out what writes to it so that I can update it permanently.

Comment: sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf - which will make the file immutable and won't be overwritten next time you start wsl

Answer (score 7):

I figured out what went wrong. In the proxy configuration of my box, an extra `http://` got prefixed to "proxy server with http".

Example..

> `http://http://proxy.mycollege.com`

and that has created problems. Corrected that, and it works perfectly.

Thanks @WhiteCoffee and @ChrisBint for your suggestions!

Comment: please tell how to change the setting.

Comment: you can change the setting by HTTP_PROXY="your server" on your terminal.

Comment: For me, using Fedora and Ubuntu, I put http://localhost in the System Settings Networking section.  The gui only expects localhost.

Comment: Unbelievably this was my problem as well. Had to edit `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score 2):

If using **Vagrant** try reloading your box. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might happen because of the overriding of resolv.conf, [This](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5420#issuecomment-944909858) answer helped me, use below every time when you set up a new WSL. `sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` - will make the file immutable and won't be overwritten next time you start wsl.

```
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "[network]
generateResolvConf = false" > /etc/wsl.conf
rm /etc/resolv.conf
echo -e "options timeout:1 attempts:1 rotate
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1" > /etc/resolv.conf
chattr -f +i /etc/resolv.conf'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I just removed the http:// from the link and it worked:

!wget [www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/pets/data/images.tar.gz](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data/pets/data/images.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this sort of problem (I was trying to install julia on VSL 2 Ubuntu on Windows) by disconnecting from the VPN of my company