# wget: unable to resolve host address

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wget

I'am getting an error with the following command:

```
> wget sources.buildroot.net
--2017-01-04 09:22:20--  http://sources.buildroot.net/
Resolving sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘sources.buildroot.net’
```

**What i have done**

- `ping sources.buildroot.net` gives `ping: unknown host sources.buildroot.net` 
  even `ping google.com` gives `ping: unknown host google.com`
  NOTE : The links can be opened using the browser.
- I changed `HTTPS_PROXY` and `HTTP_PROXY`environement variables to be equal to the value set on browser, the problem persist.
- I edited `/etc/resolv.conf` as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821521/wget-unable-to-resolve-host-address-http#answer-24821755) but the problem persist

Could you please help me resolv the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your environment variables need to be lower case.  Use `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` instead of `HTTP_PROXY`.

`man wget` has all the details.

> Wget supports proxies for both HTTP and FTP retrievals.  The standard way to specify proxy location, which Wget recognizes, is using the following environment variables:
>
> http_proxy
>
> https_proxy
>
> If set, the http_proxy and https_proxy variables should contain the URLs of the proxies for HTTP and HTTPS
>             connections respectively.