# Import swagger_client into python project to run strava API

Tags: python-3.x, swagger-2.0, python-poetry, strava

I'm trying to do some basic programming in Python, I want to be able to pull, post & edit my own data from strava.

I'm pretty new to programming, I'm using this as my 'capstone' project to develop my skills.

See https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-createActivity

I'm trying to import swagger_client but getting:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swagger_client'`

I've tried installing the command line version of swagger using:

`wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.4.13/swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar -O swagger-codegen-cli.jar`

I'm operating on ubuntu 18.04, not sure if that makes a difference.

My repo is https://github.com/RobOwen-climb/Robruns.git

I'm using poetry package manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [swagger_client in python trying to use Strava API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55657275/113116)?

Comment: I tried running step 1 `wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.4.7/swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.7.jar -O swagger-codegen-cli.jar` but I get the response `Resolving central.maven.org (central.maven.org)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘central.maven.org'` I found some further help here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821521/wget-unable-to-resolve-host-address-http] - I've tried configuring my wifi adapter with a DNS [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]  and removing `http` from the command  but I still get the same result

Comment: `central.maven.org` was moved to `repo1.maven.org`. Use this link in your command instead: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.4.13/swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar